# How to align right accounts:ui loginButtons in Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar, right-align

I'm trying to get accounts:ui loginButtons to right align in a Bootstrap Navbar. Functionality is fine, but no matter what I try, it won't go on the right. Currently, it's on the left after the Upload button. Any help appreciated.

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">REVUME</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CATEGORIES <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="digital_art">DIGITAL ART</a></li>
            <li><a href="drawing">DRAWING</a></li>
            <li><a href="graphic_design">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="illustration">ILLUSTRAION</a></li>
            <li><a href="painting">PAINTING</a></li>
            <li><a href="photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
            <li><a href="ui_ux">UI/UX</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">UPLOAD</button>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{> loginButtons align="right"}} </a>
    </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"             href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100|Luckiest+Guy|Quicksand:300|Asap:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Roboto|Signika:700" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  #right-button {
    margin-right: 20px;

  }
  #glyph {
  }
</style>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">REVUME</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CATEGORIES <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="digital_art">DIGITAL ART</a></li>
            <li><a href="drawing">DRAWING</a></li>
            <li><a href="graphic_design">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
            <li><a href="illustration">ILLUSTRAION</a></li>
            <li><a href="painting">PAINTING</a></li>
            <li><a href="photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
            <li><a href="ui_ux">UI/UX</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button id="right-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right">UPLOAD</button></li>
        <li>
        <a href="#"><span id="glyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></span> </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Use the class `navbar-right` with the element that you are trying to align at the right side.

Comment: Tried `<ul class="pull-right">
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{> loginButtons}} </a>
        </ul>` That moved it up, but not right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oops. That put the Upload Button way to the right. Then put the login glyphicon under that without access to the login form.

Comment: You need to add some css to fix this problem I just suggested the way to move it to the right

Comment: I added the css for you I think its fixed now

Comment: Got it. Works fine! I accept your answer but don't know if my up-votes are public yet. Thanks!

Comment: If it helped just accept my answer..Your upvotes won't be publicnow but you can accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' :)